# SSRS Report Builder Runs Procedure that I cannot find in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012

I have a report that calls a stored procedure name sp_rptPoolAndHottubSchedule, when I execute the procedure from report builder it runs with no problems. When I try and locate this procedure inside SSMS using the GUI or the SYS objects it is no were to be found.

What am I doing wrong? It seems like a simple thing.

[image]

Comment: One possibility is you're looking on the wrong server or in the wrong database.

Comment: Or you dont have proper permissions to view that object or the schema is different.

Comment: Slight detour....https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @TabAlleman I am connected to local host as the datastore and to the database hosted locally on that server. I am using my integrated credentials to run it so I know I must have access

Comment: @Brad I am connected to local host as the datastore and to the database hosted locally on that server. I am using my integrated credentials to run it so I know I must have access

Comment: Check the datasource credentials, if they are specific sql credentials then you are not connected to the database in the same way when you look via SSMS. If you know the credentials the datasource uses then log into SSMS with the same credentials.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Its using integrated auth, so its using my login creds

Comment: The only thing I can think to try next is to run a trace on the server and see what statement is actually being executed when you run the report.

Comment: Have you checked the master db to see if it is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- or SSMS and SSRS Report Builder run under different credentials
- or following statement was executed:

SQL:

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON [sp_rptPoolAndHottubSchedule] TO YourAccout
```

The existence of the object can be checked via:

```
-- null means that object not exists
SELECT object_id ('sp_rptPoolAndHottubSchedule')
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to locate it by object_Id

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to the correct DB, maybe a rights issue, wrong schema, etc?  Your datasource is set up correctly?   Do you get something like "`Unable to connect to datasource`" when you hit the '`query designer`' button?

Since you say it's working, but you can't find it, I suspect you may not be connected to your DB instance. When you expand your DB instance, then programmability  in SSMS - you don't see your proc listed at all. You could do a **`select object_id`** like using whatever params you need:

```
select OBJECT_ID ( '[ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name . ]   
  object_name' [ ,'object_type' ] )
```

This is documented here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL:

```
select * from sys.procedures 
where name like '%name_of_proc%'
```

And check manually like:

Assuming you're in the `Object Explorer Details (F7)` showing the list of Stored Procedures, click the Filters button and enter the name (or partial name).

[image]

If still you haven't find stored procedure name then you are looking in different server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried this method and it does not show up

Comment: Are you looking in to correct database and server name where you created reports